# How can I run this batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, sql-server

This is the batch file:

```
OSQL -S 127.0.0.1 -U sa -P password
RESTORE DATABASE DATA FROM DISK = C:\backup\data.dat
GO
EXIT
```

But after I run the `OSQL -S 127.0.0.1 -U sa -P password`, the command prompt starts with the line:

```
1>
```

After that, the batch cmd can't run. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading '[Running the osql Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213088(v=SQL.80).aspx)' i would use

```
% osql -S 127.0.0.1 -U sa -P password -i myscript.sql
```

and put

```
RESTORE DATABASE DATA FROM DISK = C:\backup\data.dat
GO
EXIT
```

into a file named `myscript.sql`